# Why there is no cuda::SIFT_CUDA in Opencv?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, sift, surf

Reading Opencv 3.0 documentation I found [cuda::SURF_CUDA](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/xfeatures2d/doc/nonfree_features.html#cuda-surf-cuda), which (I think) is the SURF algorithm implementation exploiting nvidia GPUs.

I didn't find nothing about a GPU implementation of SIFT (something like `cuda::SIFT_CUDA`). Why? Did I miss it?

Comment: No, you did not miss it. Its just that no one from the developer community has decided to implement it yet in OpenCV.

Comment: I have to say it: what a smart move, considering that SIFT is proven to be more accurate than SURF (plenty of papers about that), a GPU implementation should be done!

Comment: Well there are some other GPU implementations of SIFT available out there. e.g. [**siftgpu**](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~ccwu/siftgpu/) and [**CudaSift**](https://github.com/Celebrandil/CudaSift). Just not in OpenCV.

Comment: I totally agree, but then why not include them in OpenCV? They are really famous, I don't get why developers prefers SURF to SIFT. Anyway, these implementatios are good also for processing **one image** ? Usually GPUs  are used in computer vision when we have to process **a lot** of images together, but since sometimes there could be a consistent overhead in initializing GPUs it could be even worse than the SIFT serial version. Is this the case also, or these implementations that you linked have better performances even processing one image than the serial implementation?

Comment: I don't think they intentionally decided to not add a GPU version of SIFT. Just they lack of resources and maybe this is no more a priority as it exists other alternatives / implementations of SIFT GPU. Moreover, the algorithm is patented in some regions of the world. Also, it is **Open**CV: you don't have to pay to use it and you can't have the same expectation than for a commercial product. Also, as an Open Source project, everybody (_maybe you?_) has the possibility to **contribute to it** and not only use it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to GPU SIFT, provided by Marten Bjorkman at KTH.

It was maintained by his grad student who has since moved on to Watanabe lab, but is now back in Stockholm.  https://github.com/Celebrandil/CudaSift

Docs are unfortunately limited, but it would be an interesting exercise to merge into OpenCV3.  (Assuming any licensing conflicts can be worked out...this may be a big 'if'.)